# Expand the equation and find the value of n.

Tags: polynomials

If the equation

> \begin{equation}\sum_{i=1}^n(x+i-1)(x+i)=10n \end{equation}

has roots $r$ and $r+1$, find $n$.

Comment: Tried anything at all by any chance? Would help to know where you actually need help.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(nx^2+(2i-1)x+i^2-1)=x^2+(n^2+n-1)x+\frac{n(n^2-1)}{3}-10n=0$.

Comment: Mmm.. $\sum x^2 = n x^2$ etc.  And the summation is from $i=1$. You need to recheck that.  You should get $n x^2+n^2 x+\dfrac{n}3(n^2-31)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Given $$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x+i-1)\cdot (x+i) = 10n\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x+i)^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x+i) = 10n$$

So $$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[(x^2+i^2+2xi)-(x+i)\right] = 10n\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n}x^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)x+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i^2-i)=10n$$

Now Using $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}1=n$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

So Equation Convert into $$\displaystyle nx^2+(1+3+5+....\bf{n-terms})x+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=10n$$

So $$\displaystyle nx^2+\frac{n}{2}\left[1+2n-1\right]x+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\left[\frac{2n-2}{3}\right] = 10n$$

So $$\displaystyle x^2+nx+\frac{(n^2-1)}{3} = 10\Rightarrow 3x^2+3nx+(n^2-31) = 0$$

Now Given Here Roots $r$ and $r+1$. So $\displaystyle r+r+1 = -\frac{3n}{3} = -n\Rightarrow 2r=-(n+1)$

and $$\displaystyle r\cdot (r+1) = \frac{n^2-31}{3}\Rightarrow 2r\cdot (2r+2) = 4\left(\frac{n^2-31}{3}\right)$$

Now put $\displaystyle 2r = -(n+1)$